# Play mp4 video in ics

Tags: android

I have an application that record a movie in mp4 (MPEG_4) format and i would like to present it to the user when the recoder is over.  My code look like that:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(path), "video/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

It works in 2.2 and 3
But it dose not work in ICS.
Why? someone maybe have other solution to my problem?

Comment: in the logcat see what intent is being sent when u play someother video on ICS..

Comment: logcat: INFO/ActivityManager(193): START {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://media/external/video/media/692 typ=video/* cmp=com.google.android.gallery3d/com.android.gallery3d.app.MovieActivity (has extras)} from pid 8957

Comment: I didnt save my file in this path: //media/external/video/media/692

Comment: I dont understand what is this strange dat param

Comment: try using the full path; Instead of "Intent.ACTION_VIEW" use "android.Intent.ACTION_VIEW" though I'm cent percent sure this is not the problem. just try

Comment: Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); Uri name = Uri.parse("content://media/external/video/media/692"); String type = "video/*"; myIntent.setDataAndType(name, type); 
how can i find "content://media/external/video/media/692" if i have the movie name??

Answer (score 0):

It's because of default codecs, I think they've been changed in ICS. However, you should try another .mp4 file - some of them are still playable